# Как собрать include из define

Tags: c++, c, препроцессор

Как из

```
#define filename myfilename
#define path ../driver/
```

перейти к

```
#include INCLUDE_DRIVER;
```

которое после препроцессинга перейдет в

```
#include "../driver/myfilename.h"
```

Я потратил уже немало времени, на различные комбинации ##, но так и не пришел к тому что нужно. Я бы продолжил эксперементы, если бы был хорошо виден результат.

Comment: честно говоря какими-то извращенствами попахивает

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что задача решается левой рукой через правое ухо... Огласите весь список, пожалуйста. То есть настоящую цель.

Comment: В большом проекте должен быть подключен конкретный файл (один из 20 вариантов). В сотне мест. Для этого очевидно нужно задать имя цели дефайном. Так как тип цели используется не только для подключения, то вписывать в один дефайн ещё и путь неправильно.

Comment: используйте Makefile (или Вашу любимую систему сборки). Там определяйте нужные переменные и генерируйте h файл. Который потом подключайте куда нужно.

В особо тяжелых случаях можно написать свою программу на с++/перл/любимом языке, который будет вначале собираться и генерировать хедер.

Comment: *Для этого очевидно* - нет, не очевидно. Такие вещи генерятся чем-то типа `automake` и пр.

Comment: @KoVadim, Хотелось бы уйти от make, плюс вопрос интересен и просто из академического интереса.

Comment: Если Ваш проект больше 2-3 файлов, систему сборки лучше иметь. Оно позволит человеку со стороны быстро собрать проект, а не искать в ридми "вот строка для сборки в консоли".

Comment: Это система которая должна интегрироваться в другие проекты, достаточно легко. С минимальным порогом вхождения, кросплатформенная, в исходниках. То есть это не готовое приложение и при добавлении системы сборки она закономерно налетит на конфликт с системой сборки основного проекта, которая может оказаться любой. Это отдельная задача на самом деле что выбрать. С ходу решить не получается.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Похоже, в gcc это не решается (по крайней мере корректно). Мне
>   удалось "сделать" только подавив всю диагностику через

```
> gcc -E c1.c /tmp/t.c 2>/dev/null; gcc /tmp/t.c. /
```

> Вообще в документации по поводу конкатенации пишут: However, two tokens that don't together form a
>   valid token cannot be pasted together. For example, you cannot
>   concatenate x with + in either order. If you try, the preprocessor
>   issues a warning and emits the two tokens. Whether it puts white space
>   between the tokens is undefined.

– avp 25 май в 13:26

Answer (score 17):

> ```
> #define path ../driver/
> ```

А кавычки кто ставить будет?

http://codepad.org/vi8lh5nI

---

> Там два дефайна определяют путь в условии.

Разобрался. Вот работающая последовательность шагов:
http://codepad.org/rGostnci
http://codepad.org/wCx3Of1Y
http://codepad.org/VpQ3O1AJ

Итоговый вариант кода:

```
#define STD std 
#define IOH io.h

#define STR(x) #x
#define JOIN(x,y) STR(x##y)
#define INC(x,y) JOIN(x,y)

#include INC(STD,IOH)

int main(void)
{
return !printf("YES");
}
```

Почему так?

1. Объединение `"таких" "строк"` делается потом. Include не должен содержать такого. Поэтому разворачивание аргумента в строку (единственного аргумента) должно быть сделано на последнем шаге. Это делает `STR`.
2. Для передачи аргументов в `STR` их надо объединить - это делает `JOIN`.
3. Поскольку `include` передаёт то, что само по себе define, если сразу вызвать `JOIN`, то объединятся имена дефайнов, а не значения. Добавляем ещё один уровень, чтобы они развернулись - это `INC`.

Собственно всё, оно работает.

---

> А теперь меняем std и io.h на данные ТС, запускаем в gcc и получаем кучу ругани

Проверил: http://codepad.org/WY0TkYMS

```
Line 0: error: pasting "/" and "myfilename" does not give a valid preprocessing token
Line 27: error: ../driver/myfilename: No such file or directory
```

Возможно, с этим можно сделать что-то при помощи ключей компиляции. Потому что есть какая-то мутная ошибка про слеш, но дальше в 27й строке делается попытка подключить файл с правильно сформированным именем (естественно, на codepad'e его нет).

К сожалению, я не знаток ключей компиляции gcc. Возможно, кто-то сможет подсказать, как исправить эту проблему.

---

Как насчёт использования фиктивного каталога, из которого потом поднимемся вверх?
http://codepad.org/OCpT6U2B
Спасибо **avp** за идею.

```
#define filename _/../myfilename
#define path ../driver/_

#define STR(x) #x
#define JOIN(x,y) STR(x##y)
#define INC(x,y) JOIN(x,y)

#include INC(path,filename)

int main(void)
{
return !printf("YES");
}
```

Comment: Там два дефайна определяют путь в условии.

Comment: @Rinin, понял. Подумаю.

Comment: @Rinin, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Классно! Я был уверен, что так нельзя сделать.

Comment: @ixSci, я даже твой ответ увидеть успел :) Там же специальная форма с макросом есть у include. Пока я экспериментировал с define'ами, у меня тоже начало складываться ощущение, что не выйдет. Но потом я заменил макросы на литералы и понял, как надо добраться до работающего варианта :)

Comment: Круто. И неожиданно.

Comment: А теперь меняем std и io.h на данные ТС, запускаем в gcc и получаем кучу ругани типа `c1.c:1:22: error: pasting "/" and "myfilename" does not give a valid preprocessing token` / К сожалению, не всен тут так просто

Comment: @avp, дополнил ответ.

Comment: В студии у меня работает следующий код: `#include INC(./Classes.h)`, где `Classes.h` существующий файл в текущей директории.

Comment: Похоже, в gcc это не решается (по крайней мере корректно). Мне удалось "сделать" только подавив всю диагностику через `gcc -E c1.c >/tmp/t.c 2>/dev/null; gcc /tmp/t.c`. / Вообще в [документации](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) по поводу конкатенации пишут: `However, two tokens that don't together form a valid token cannot be pasted together. For example, you cannot concatenate x with + in either order. If you try, the preprocessor issues a warning and emits the two tokens. Whether it puts white space between the tokens is undefined.`

Comment: @Rinin, а вообще-то Вам правильно заметили в комментариях об извращенности такого подхода. Возможно наиболее удобным решением Вашей проблемы будет использование опции `-I` компилятора (каталог, в котором ищем заголовочные файлы (можно задать много таких опций), которые можно прописать в переменной `CFLAGS` в Makefile.

Comment: А если подойти к решению с долей шутки `
#define STD /usr/inclu
#define IOH de/stdio.h`, то все работает "на ура"

Comment: Да, это "классический" вариант использования ##, проблема как раз в том, что требуется добавить ещё путь (со слешами) и .h в конце. Спасибо за изыскания, сам пока тоже продолжаю.

Comment: @avp, на основе твоей идеи: http://codepad.org/OCpT6U2B

Comment: Идея интересная, но к сожалению, без каталога `driver/__` работать не будет.

Comment: Проблема в том что что-то оканчивающееся на / (например) не соответствует ни одному из типов токенов препроцессора. Не пунктуация и не строка. И при любых промежуточных подобных результатах тоже идёт ошибка.

Comment: @Rinin: Ну это как раз не большая проблема. Вместо `"/usr/include/"` + `"stdio.h"` делайте `"/usr/inlide/."` + `"/stdio.h"`, например.

Comment: @VladD, cлеша ни в одной из частей быть не должно. Как и точки.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, вариант  `#define STD /usr/inclu #define IOH de/stdio.h` же работает? Или нет?

Comment: @VladD, компилятор хочет, чтобы первый кусок кончался, а второй начинался таким образом, чтобы их стык принадлежал одному токену. Т. е. оба символа (последний в первой строке и первый во второй) должны быть буквенно-цифровыми.

Comment: Прикольно. `++` - это валидный токен. Осталось понять, каиой токен c++ сочетается с файловой системой подходящим образом.